# how to change the column spacing and ticks with plotly python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, heatmap, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a pandas dataframe into a plotly heatmap. I was able to do so but the width of the heatmap is very small, and the ticks do not have the granularity that I desire.

The data is a 2D dataframe where the column labels and index are both floats. with plotly.express as px I plot the data like so

```
px.imshow(df, origin='lower', color_continuous_scale='viridis',
          labels={"x": "OF Ratio (%weight)", "y": "Pressure (atm)", "hover":
          "Isp"}, title="Specific  Impulse of LOX, RP1 Engine")
```

[plotly plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJNqb.png)

I would instead want to be getting each individaul index and column label to be written and for the image sizing to be bigger and more square. like so

[Example of what I want image to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avcaf.png)

How can I tweak the ticks, and tick spacing of the plotly plot?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `imshow` renders graphs with a 1:1 aspect ratio.

The differing domain ranges for your axes (57.5-10 vs. 3.8-1) result in the X-axis being approximately 17 times smaller than the Y-axis.

To fix this quickly you can use the optional argument `aspect="auto"`, which fills the allotted plot area as best it can.

For more details on setting a specific aspect ratio: https://plotly.com/python/axes/#fixed-ratio-axes

Answer (score 0):

Solution (credit to Thomas).

```
px.imshow(plot, width=600, height=600, origin='lower', color_continuous_scale='viridis', labels={"x": "OF Ratio (%weight)", "y": "Pressure (atm)", "hover": "Isp"}, title="Specific Impulse of LOX, RP1 Engine", aspect="auto")
```

prints the following
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEvu.png)

imshow sizes the axes based on their numerical value when possible. my x range was 1-3.8 and my y range 10-57.5 so the x-axis was ~ 17 times smaller

by adding aspect= "auto" the graph fills up all the space available to it.